# python serve image and data using python BaseHttpRequestHandler

Tags: python, http, multipartform-data, basehttprequesthandler

Hi I've the following code.

```
class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    PAGE = """
    <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>
                    </title>
                    <link href='/favicon.ico' rel='shortcut icon'>
                    <style>
                        img {
                            width: 80%;
                            height: auto;
                        }
                       .left{
                           float:left;
                       }
                       .right{
                           float:left;
                       }
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                   <div class="left">
                       <img src='/mjpeg'>
                   </div>
                   <div class="left">
                       <!-- SHOW DATA HERE -->
                   </div>

              """

       PAGE_AFTER = """
            </body>
        </html>
"""

visualization_queue = None
predictionObj = None

def __init__(self, visualization_queue, *args, **kwargs):
    self.visualization_queue = visualization_queue
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


def do_GET(self):

    print('path hai ye')
    print(self.path)
    if self.path == '/mjpeg':
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header(
            'Content-type',
            'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--jpgboundary'
        )
        self.end_headers()

        while True:
            frame = self.get_info_from_queue() """<-- irrelevant"""

            if frame is None:
                print('no image from stream')
                time.sleep(1)
                continue

            try:
                ret, jpg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
                self.wfile.write(bytes("--jpgboundary\n", "utf8"))
                self.send_header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
                self.send_header('Content-length', len(jpg))
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(jpg)

                # time.sleep(self.config.delay)
            except (BrokenPipeError, ConnectionResetError):
                print('connection closed')
                break
    elif self.path == "/favicon.ico":
        print('getting favicon')
        icon = io.open("Common/logo-alten.png", "rb").read()
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'mage/x-icon')
        self.send_header('Content-length', len(icon))
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(icon)
    elif self.path == "/":
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes(self.PAGE + self.PAGE_AFTER, "utf8"))
    else:
        print('error', self.path)
        self.send_response(404)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes('<html><head></head><body>', "utf8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes('<h1>{0!s} not found</h1>'.format(self.path), "utf8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes('</body></html>', "utf8"))

    return


class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    """Handle requests in a separate thread."""
```

I am trying to show a video on the `localhost:8080` of my server. The problem is that I am able to succesfully send video frames as you can see in the following part of the code .

```
ret, jpg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
self.wfile.write(bytes("--jpgboundary\n", "utf8"))
self.send_header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
self.send_header('Content-length', len(jpg))
self.end_headers()
self.wfile.write(jpg)
```

What I want now is also to send additional data in the form of html, for e.g

```
<ol>
  <li>Person: 0</li>
  <li>cars: 5</li>
</ol>
```

To show along on the side of the page. Can anybody point me in the right direction ? Any solutions ?

Thanks.

Comment: You generally don't... you could put the jpeg encoded as the "src" of the image element and then the rest of the content as additional data, then count the length of that combined, or, you put the image returned as a separate function with a link to the image and just return the html that indicates to the browser it should then retrieve the image from another link... that or just use a micro-framework such as [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and save yourself a huge amount of frustration...

Comment: hi Jon thanks for the answer. Is it possible for you to give a very simple small code example. I'll highly appreciate it.

Comment: Start with https://stackabuse.com/serving-static-files-with-flask/ - that'll cover everything you're trying to achieve... (but in a much, much, simpler way :p)

Comment: thanks man that'll work